# How to execute Play complete subproject from non-Play root?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

Using Play Framework 2.2, I have generated simple default application using `play new` called `foo-web`.

Now I want to make it part of multi-module project with another non-web project called `foo-core` that was created with `play new` (even thought it's not going to be a web project in the future).

I've created `foo` directory, put both subprojects inside it and created `build.sbt`.

It looks like this:

- `foo` top-level directory

  - `foo-core` complete Play project from `play new`
  - `foo-web` complete Play project from `play new`
  - `build.sbt`

**build.sbt** for the multi-module build is as follows:

```
import play.Project._

name := "foo"

organization := "com.foo"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

// fails to build if I omit this
play.Project.playJavaSettings

lazy val core = Project("foo-core", file("foo-core"))

lazy val web = Project("foo-web", file("foo-web")).dependsOn(core)

lazy val foo = Project("foo", file(".")).aggregate(core, web)
```

This compiles and packages just fine but when I `run` or `web/run` it seems to start play with empty route configuration presumably from empty `/foo` project instead of `/foo/foo-web/`.

How can I tell play that it should run `foo-web` project?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Well, I thought it was obvious that I want to have a working web page (i.e. make `play run` execute `foo-web` project).

Comment: You should be able to switch project by `project foo-web` and then execute there `run`. You don't need to have this line `play.Project.playJavaSettings` in your `/foo/build.sbt`. Alternatively you can have web project in your `foo` and modules in separate projects as [advertised in the original Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects)

Comment: Thanks, `project foo-web` does the trick! Can you write it as an answer so I can mark it as such ?